# Extract PHP variables into Android?

Tags: php, android

Before I embark on my university project I need to know if there is a way to extract the PHP variables from a PHP file into Android?

There is a PHP file on a server that have all the variables that I want. You can obviously upload the file to the device, but is there a way to extract all the variables in that file?

All the values that I need are in that PHP file. There is some lines of code before all the variables.

I can not modify the PHP file as that is already generated by another program elsewhere. The file is always named the same. Can someone please pass me in the right direction?

So I have this PHP file with variables in it, below is the actual first few lines:

```
<?php> 
if ( isset($_REQUEST['sce']) && strtolower($_REQUEST['sce']) == 'view' ) {
//--self downloader --
$filenameReal = __FILE__;
$download_size = filesize($filenameReal);
header('Pragma: public');
header('Cache-Control: private');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header("Content-type: text/plain");
header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
header("Content-Length: $download_size");
header('Connection: close');
readfile($filenameReal);
exit;
}

// General OR Non Weather Specific/SUN/MOON

// ========================================

$time =  '19:20';   // current time
$date =  '22/12/14';    // current date
$sunrise =  '08:04';    // sun rise time (make sure you have the correct lat/lon
//                  in view/sun moon)
$time_minute =  '20';   // Current minute
$time_hour =  '19'; // Current hour
$date_day =  '22';  // Current day
$date_month =  '12';    // Current month
$date_year =  '2014';   // Current year
$monthname =  'December';   // Current month name
$dayname =  'Monday';   // Current day name
$sunset =  '15:53'; // sunset time
$moonrise =  '07:56';   // moon rise time
$milestokm = 1.609344; // to convert miles to kms
.
.
.and many more...
?>
```

I want to display all those variables on the screen, not all of them. Some of them.

Comment: Are you able to create a new php file which can echo the values of those variables as json?

Comment: Yes I'm sure I can. The other file gets created by another program on another server and uploaded to my server and overwrites the other file that is there. However the file will need to be created on the android device to be uploaded to the server. It would have to be done by the app.

Comment: It's probably a good idea if you can outline what it is you're trying to achieve. You might get some alternative ideas.

Comment: Does the above elaborate more?

Answer (score 0):

PHP will run on a server only, if you want to take values from it then it is required that it has been exposed by any means for.e.g REST endpoint. Now assume your server is up and running, at your android app you need to make HTTP request to the endpoint exposing the values. that ways you can get the values.

I must say you should study about web concepts, copying value from PHP will not fetch you values. Also go through these links
This is how REST endpoint are exposed :http://coreymaynard.com/blog/creating-a-restful-api-with-php/

This is how android application uses rest client to consumes those endpoints thhttp://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/calling-restful-services-from-your-android-app/

Comment: It seems to be more or less in the direction I want to go.

Comment: since the Rest Based communication will be done either using XML or JSON you can go for Spring Rest Client for android, it has support for converting your data from JSON/XML to your java object and vide versa, find an example here(for XML) http://www.concretepage.com/android/android-spring-resttemplate-xml-integration-example